# Prepend object key to object in angular controller

Tags: angularjs, object, prepend

I thought this was a javascript problem but I'm not sure.

Say I have an object like this

```
   var foo = {
        foo1: 'name', 
        foo2: 'name2' 
    }
```

and when I make a post call with this in angular in the console the post body shows

```
{foo1: 'name', foo2: 'name2'}
```

Great, that's all great.

In my backend though let's say the request body needs to be:

```
{type: {foo1: 'name', foo2: 'name2'}}
```

Okay, so in angular, I have that type key in $scope.type and the foo object in $scope.foo

I tried to achieve this by just going

```
$scope.foo = {$scope.type:$scope.foo};
```

That didn't work, it just said that the '.' in $scope.type wasn't allowed.

So then I tried setting a var type = $scope.type then put

```
$scope.foo = {type: $scope.foo};
```

which worked except the response post was the word 'type' and not the actual value itself.
What's going on here? why can't I prepend the key $scope.type to my foo object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use dynamic values in an objects braces for the name type.
Instead you should do something like this:

```
var obj = {};
obj[$scope.type] = $scope.foo;
$scope.foo = obj;
```

Comment: Thanks I got it working with underscore js to just change the whole object itself so I didn't have to preprend this. But I did try this solution and it worked! Makes sense thanks a lot.